# Can't access protected routes in nodejs using bearer token through postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, bearer-token

I am trying to make `get request` to my protected routes using `bearer token` and it returns `unautorized`, even after sending token through header.

I am using bearer token on nodejs, expressjs app using mlab remote database
I registered new user, then I logged with that email and it sent me back a token(as expected).

When I sent this token through header of  other route without login it returns `Unautorized`.

my steps are

1) registered with new email

[image: first I registered]

2) login request successful

[image: login request 2nd]

3) failed `get request` to route `localhost:5000/api/users/current`, and returns Unautorized.

[image: unautho]

`user.js` file has

```
// users.js for authentication and authorization

const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const gravatar = require("gravatar");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const keys = require("../../config/keys");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const passport = require("passport");

// Load User Model to check existing email is used for registration or not?
const User = require("../../models/User");

// @route       GET request to api/users/test
// @description Tests users route
// @access      Public, without login
router.get("/test", (req, res) => res.json({ msg: "Users Works" }));

// @route       GET request to api/users/register
// @description new registration of user.
// @access      Public, without login first register

router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ email: "Email value exists already." });
    } else {
      console.log("no user found of this email in DB");
      const avatar = gravatar.url(req.body.email, {
        s: "200", //Size of gravatar in pixels
        r: "pg", //rating,
        d: "mm" //default value= 'mm'
      });
      // create user
      const newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        avatar,
        password: req.body.password
      });

      // gensalt(noOfSalts_of_Iterations,(err,salt_result)=>{})
      bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        // hash(plaintext,salt,callback(err,resultant ciphertext))
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log("error in bcrypt.hash()");
            throw err;
          }
          //assign salted hash to password
          newUser.password = hash;

          // Save new password in datebase, overriding plaintext;
          newUser
            .save()
            .then(user => res.json(user)) // if yes,then send it as argument in brackets.
            .catch(err =>
              console.log("Error occured in saving hash password in DB\n")
            );
        });
      });
    }
  });
});

// @route       GET request to api/users/login
// @description Login/signing-in registered user. return JWT token
// @access      Public

router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  // find user to match it's password
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
    //check if no user
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ email: "User's email   found." });
    }

    // else if do this..

    // if user's email-id is found then match it's password-hash with local-database
    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(isMatch => {
      if (isMatch) {
        // user pswd matched => then return JWT token back for authentication
        // res.json({ msg: "Success" });
        const payload = { it: user.id, name: user.name, avatar: user.avatar };

        // created JWT token
        // now sign token
        // jwt.sign(payload, secretKey, expire-time, callback );

        // jwt.sign

        jwt.sign(
          payload,
          keys.secretOrKey,
          { expiresIn: 3600 },
          (err, token) => {
            res.json({
              success: true,
              token: "bearer " + token
            });
          }
        );
      } else {
        // pswd doesn't matched
        return res.status(400).json({ password: "Password didn't match" });
      }
    });
  });
});

// @route       GET request to api/users/current  - current user with token
// @description Return current user
// @access      Private, can't go without login

router.get(
  "/current",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.json({ msg: "Success" });
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

data is stored succesfully at remote db `mlab`, but I can't figureout what's problem.
[image: screenshot]

my Github repo of this project is [this](https://github.com/ganeshdeshmukh1612/connect-geeks/commits/master)

Comment: I have tried renaming `bearer` to `Bearer`, but it didn't worked.

Comment: Try removing completely bearer word and space.

Comment: @vitomadio, It tried this now after restarting everything and newly logged, but it didn't work. link https://i.imgur.com/i9lBMsq.png

Comment: Remove the authorization that you have set in header tab. Click on Authorization tab. In dropdown choose bearer token and enter your token value only on the right side and then go back to headers tab to confirm if it there. And try sending out request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Look at the Line of your code  Users.js Line 88 the payload id is stored in 'it'

```
const payload = { it: user.id, name: user.name, avatar: user.avatar };
```

But in your passport.js

```
User.findById(jwt_payload.id)
```

you are extracting it by id so if you use here **jwt_payload.it the you will get message success**

Comment: I never thought a typo can be the that serious problem. sometimes small mistakes can't be seen. :)   output now https://imgur.com/a/pqFFvHq

Comment: ya sometimes it could be.